# Formatting Date to dd-MMM in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've been searching this and couldn't quite find it. I have an object in a NSDictionary that contains a NSDate. Now standard NSDate objects are pretty long. and I want to show the user in dd-MMM format.

For eg: The original date may be `2012-04-23 00:00:00 +0000`, for which I want the date to appear as `23 Apr`

I tried using NSDateComponents and NSDateFormatter but it didn't quite work. Probably I'm not figuring out the correct usage FOR the required format.

Here's the code for better understanding:

```
            NSLog(@"From Dictionary, Date = %@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"]);
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"]; 
            NSString *dateString = [tmpDict objectForKey: @"eventDate"];
            NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];

            NSLog(@"MY DATE: %@",date);
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM"];
            NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
            NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@",formattedDateString);
```

The output is 2012-05-19 07:30:56 for `From Dictionary, Date` and null for Formatted Date and MY DATE. And `tmpDict` is the Dictionary Object that I'm using.

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following from [Duncan C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c)'s answer.

If the date is represented as a string, first turn it into a date and then use the NSDateFormatter on it. Assuming the format will remain the same it would be

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"]; 
NSString *dateString = [dictionaryObject objectForKey: @"eventDate"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
```

Then you can do what you are doing at the moment to the `date` object.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it still didn't work. I'll edit the question to reflect the tried code.

Comment: The issue is with your date format you have in the string, you say it's supposed to be 2012-04-23 00:00:00 +0000, but it actually is 2012-04-23 00:00:00. You have to make sure it's only one of the two at all times and adjust the dateFormatter format accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

NSDate *myDate=[tmpDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"];
NSLog(@"MY DATE: %@",myDate);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@",formattedDateString);

I get the output in MY DATE but not in formattedDateString. I get a NULL there.

Comment: What's the output for the first log?

Comment: MY DATE: 2012-05-19 07:30:56
Formatted Date: (null)

Comment: Can you try NSLog(@"MY DATE: %@", [myDate description]); ?

Comment: MY DATE: 2012-05-19 07:30:56
That's the output the of [myDate description].

Comment: Something has to be wrong with your date object. Try `NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];`. This will set myDate to the current date, then format and log it.

Comment: Your code works for [NSDate date]...but it isn't working for what I want. I'm also saving the same object of date to Core Data and that's working fine. Wonder what's going wrong with the formatter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the object you are fetching from your dictionary with the key eventDate is a string, not a date.

Try this code:

```
NSDate *myDate=[tmpDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"]; 
NSLog(@"myDate class = %@", [myDate class]);
```

I bet it shows a class of NSString or one of it's subclasses, not an NSDate.

Comment: Yep..it shows __NSCFString referring it to NSString.
Any workaround?

Comment: You need to create 2 date formatters. Let's call them inputDateFormatter and outputDateFormatter. inputDateFormatter would be set up to accept a date string in the format of your incoming dates and convert it to an NSDate. Then you'd take the resulting NSDate and convert it to your output format using outputDateFormatter. I'm no expert on date formatters, and always have to wade through the docs to figure out how to handle a date in a particular format.

Comment: Okay..I tried that as well and it still doesn't work. I have updated the question to reflect the changes. And thanks for the support, nevertheless. It is highly appreciated.