# Display date in "st" , "nd", "rd" and "th" format

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, nsdateformatter

I have to display date in different format.

For eg. 
21st July

I didn't find anything to convert my date in this format. If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Date to dd-MMM in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574248/formatting-date-to-dd-mmm-in-ios)

Answer (score 20):

**Swift**

```
extension Date {

    func dateFormatWithSuffix() -> String {
        return "dd'\(self.daySuffix())' MMMM yyyy"
    }

    func daySuffix() -> String {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(.day, from: self)
        let dayOfMonth = components.day
        switch dayOfMonth {
        case 1, 21, 31:
            return "st"
        case 2, 22:
            return "nd"
        case 3, 23:
            return "rd"
        default:
            return "th"
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = date.dateFormatWithSuffix()
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
// Output for current date: 22nd May 2019
```

Comment: This is not language agnostic. You could use `NumberFormatter` with `.numberStyle = ordinal` but then some languages also don't expect an ordinal style in their dates.

Comment: @jowie you are correct! I answered to primary question regarding "st", "nd", "rd" and "th". For other languages it is complicated)

Answer (score 13):

```
    func setCurrentDate() {
        let date = Date()

        // Use this to add st, nd, th, to the day
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current

        //Set other sections as preferred
        let monthFormatter = DateFormatter()
        monthFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"

        // Works well for adding suffix
        let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"

        let dayString = dayFormatter.string(from: date)
        let monthString = monthFormatter.string(from: date)

        // Add the suffix to the day
        let dayNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(dayString)!)
        let day = numberFormatter.string(from: dayNumber)!

        yourDateLabel.text = "\(day) \(monthString)"
}
```

Label will  currently be set to **25th May**

Answer (score -3):

You can use NSDateFormatter to display your NSDate. It has properties such as dateStyle, and timeStyle which can easily be altered to get your desired format. If you need more flexibility there's the dateFormat property as well.

```
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```