# How to convert "2021-05-23T12:09:18Z" to date format as 23rd June 12:09 pm

Tags: ios, swift

this is the code below. I appreciate any help . Thank you!

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
               
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021-05-23T12:09:18Z")
             
print("Converted Date -- \(convertedDate)")
```

Comment: You have now a `Date`, so now use a new `DateFormatter` (or change previous one), and set its `dateFormat` to have something like `23rd June 12:09 pm`. What's in your opinion the `dateFormat` that would create that? The doc if you want http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns But the 'rd' might be tricky to get.

Comment: I hope it's a typo that you want 2021-05-23 to be formatted to 23rd June :)

Comment: If the issue is with getting an ordinal number (23rd) then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606168/9223839)

Comment: Yes I need 23"rd"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's very simple, you need second formatter, which format you `Date` to string. Example code

```
extension Date {
        func dateFormatWithSuffix() -> String {
            return "'\(self.daySuffix())' MMMM, h:mm a"
        }
    
        func daySuffix() -> String {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(.day, from: self)
            let dayOfMonth = components.day
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
            return numberFormatter.string(from: dayOfMonth as! NSNumber)!
        }
    }
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                   
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021-05-23T12:09:18Z")
    
    let dateFormatterNormal = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterNormal.dateFormat = convertedDate?.dateFormatWithSuffix()
    dateFormatterNormal.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatterNormal.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let endDate = dateFormatterNormal.string(from: convertedDate ?? Date())
    
    print("Converted Date -- \(endDate)")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdVPf.png)
For detail about dateFormat visit this [site](https://nsdateformatter.com) and go to Reference
For adding `rd`, you need to add rd in quotes in dateFormat

Comment: This does not print "23rd"

Comment: And you added an extra comma and didn't handle the time zone properly

Comment: So "1rd" would be an acceptable output on June 1st? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, it will work with rd and timezone. I add screenshots

Comment: That's not how ordinal numbers work in english, I'm afraid.

Comment: DateFormatter supports different locales so that the month can be printed in the users own language, your daySuffix only supports English.

Comment: In addition, the code as posted doesn't compile, and still does not deal with timezones correctly (try e.g. with 2021-05-23T23:59:18Z when you're in any other timezone that GMT)

Comment: I update and it now using current user locale now and NumberFormatter,

Answer (score 0):

You already have the input formatter correctly defined but you will need two more, one date formatter for the output and one formatter to get the day of month correct

```
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.locale = .current
outputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM hh:mm a"

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
numberFormatter.locale = .current
```

Note that you need to set the time zone for the second date formatter and that it and the number formatter needs a Locale set, I am using the users current locale here since this should be respected.

With that set the whole conversion becomes

```
if let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021-05-23T12:09:18Z") {
    let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: convertedDate)

    if let dayString = numberFormatter.string(from: day as NSNumber) {
        let output = "\(dayString) \(outputFormatter.string(from: convertedDate))"
        print(output)
    }
}
```

The solution for formatting the day of month was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605822/converting-date-from-date-string-in-swift/64606168#64606168)

Output for this with an English locale is

> 23rd May 12:09 PM

and an example with a Swedish locale

> 23:e maj 12:09 em

Following a comment by @LeoDabus I decided to make a more localisable version that respects if day should be printed before or after the month. Assuming the formatters are the same as before and already declared this function can be used

```
func formatDate(_ date: String, locale: Locale = .current) -> String? {
    outputFormatter.locale = locale
    numberFormatter.locale = locale
    guard let inputDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
        return nil }
    let dayOfMonth = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: inputDate)
    
    guard let ordinalDay = numberFormatter.string(for: dayOfMonth),
          let output = outputFormatter.string(for: inputDate) else {
        return nil }
    
    return output.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\(dayOfMonth)\\b",
                                       with: ordinalDay,
                                       options: .regularExpression)
}
```

A simple test

```
for locale in [Locale(identifier: "en_US"), Locale(identifier: "sv_SE"),Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")] {
    if let date = formatDate("2021-05-23T12:09:18Z", locale: locale) {
        print("\(locale): \(date)")
    }
}
```

> en_US (fixed): May 23rd, 2021
> sv_SE (fixed): 23:e maj 2021
> pt_BR (fixed): 23º de maio de 2021

And if we are going to respect what language/format etc the user has chosen completely then we ignore the ordinal number handling

```
func formatDate(_ date: String, locale: Locale = .current) -> String? {
    outputFormatter.locale = locale
    numberFormatter.locale = locale
    guard let inputDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
        return nil }

    return outputFormatter.string(for: inputDate)
}
```

and the same test would generate

> en_US (fixed): May 23, 2021
> sv_SE (fixed): 23 maj 2021
> pt_BR (fixed): 23 de maio de 2021

Comment: Note that this will return UTC time. I know OP asked the same time as the original string but IMO you should warn him about it. The correct time should be displayed using the current timezone.Note also that in US the correct result should be `June 23rd`. Btw no need to cast your day to NSNumber. You can use `Formatter`'s  `string(for: Any)` method `numberFormatter.string(for: day)`

Comment: I deliberately used UTC time here but maybe a comment about that is needed. The second part is interesting to look into, I would need to use a predefined format and then identify the day and replace it with a ordinal value.

Comment: I don’t think OP should use ordinal. The correct is to respect the localized format based on a template where  you only define the components

Comment: in Brazil the only day that you can use ordinal is the 1st

Comment: Fair point about using ordinal but that is what the question is about. I get "23º" when using Brazil locale for the number formatter, is this only for standalone numbers then and not for dates?

Comment: We have ordinal as everybody else but it is not used when displaying dates other than the 1st day of the month. You can say `1º de Abril de 2021` but not `2º de Abril de 2021`